# How to redirect the entire page from a dynamically loaded ajax file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, redirect

I have a page which is pretty basic.  There is a jquery script that runs when a user clicks on a menu item.  The jquery runs a ajax to load the content of ANOTHER page inside a div tag.  The page that loads checks to make sure the user is logged in still.  The problem is i can not redirect the entire page back to the login screen.

META HTML REDIRECT
i have tried this.  The issue here, not all the browsers redirect - such as FF.  And I really don't like this way.

HEADER REDIRECT
I have tried to insert a header redirect in the page that loads.  The issues here is, the ajax inserts the login page inside the div tag... resulting in a website inside of a website.

Is there any other way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: When you send back the response to the server from the ajax call, return a json encoded array...make one of the array elements `redirect` as the key, and `true/false` as the value, detect `data.redirect ==` in your `success(data){` function, and then do `window.location = whatever` inside of the conditional, otherwise append the page data, or append it and then redirect it, whatever you want.

Comment: Ah, thats it!  Seems like simple logic to me.  Thanks for the help!  I was lost :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to redirect.  Try `window.location.replace(your_login_url)` which  is similar to a HTTP redirect.